# Android SQLite Exception: unable to close due to unfinalised statements

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am writing an android shopping manager application and have come across an error when trying to close one of my SQLite database tables.

```
ItemsDb idb = new ItemsDb(this);

idb.open();

ArrayList<String> itemNames = idb.getItemNames();

for(int i=0; i < itemNames.size(); i++){

    String itemName = itemNames.get(i);

    String itemID = idb.getItemID(itemName);
    String itemName = idb.getItemNames().get(i);
    String itemPrices = idb.getItemPrices().get(i);
    String itemQuantity = idb.getItemQuantities().get(i);               
    String dateBought = idb.getDateBought(itemName);    
    String decayRate = idb.getDecayRate(itemName);
    String decayType = idb.getDecayType(itemName);
    String lastDecay = idb.getLastDecay(itemName);
    String prevQuantity = idb.getPreviousQuantity(itemName);
}

idb.close();
```

This doesn't happen with other calls to this class so and I am wondering if it is because there is a loop with a lot of calls to the database here. 
The error is `SQLite Exception: unable to close due to unfinalised statements`.

The error line from the "ItemsDb" class is here

```
    public ItemsDb(Context c){

        ourContext = c;
    }

    public ItemsDb open() throws SQLException{
        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close(){
        ourHelper.close();
    }
```

Apparently SQLite3 has a finalize method for destroying previous DB calls but I am not sure how to implement this or even if it is necessary here.

Any help on this would be great.

Comment: Are you using any cursors in your statements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems the problem was cursor related, thanks Jivings. I wasn't closing the cursor after I queried the database, which meant certain references to the database were invalid.

```
public String getName(String id) throws SQLException{
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ItemID, KEY_NAME};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ItemID + "='" + id + "'", null, null, null, null);
    if(c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        String name = c.getString(1);
        c.close();
        return name;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Calling "c.close" seemed to do the trick.