# Android & SQLite - Occasional error 'unable to close due to unfinalised statements'

Tags: android, sqlite

I seem to get the above error every so often in (an insert heavy) part of my code.  I know normally this means there is an open Cursor within the connection but I have been through checking all my cursors are in try finally blocks and closed.
Also in logcat the error reads 'sqlite3_close(...) failed: 5 which I think means the database is busy?

The error can be 'ignored' if I add the following code to my finally block where the database connection is closed.

```
  finally
  {
    writer.endTransaction();
    boolean successAtClose = false;
    while(successAtClose == false)
    {
      try
      {
        writer.close();
        successAtClose = true;
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    dbConn.releaseLock();
  }
```

When stepping through the code above the 'e.printStackTrace()' is hit once but on the second attempt the 'writer.close()' does not throw an error.

Just to reiterate, this problem doesn't even happen every time the code block runs, the same data can be inserted say 5/6 times and only throw the error on one of these times.  In addition the error does not reoccur straight away after happening once but continues to pop-up at random intervals.

Does anyone know why this might occur? Or a better way to recover from this than the finally code above? (Since it will take me a long time to add this to all my database code.)

ADDED:

Database is opened with a custom `SQLiteOpenHelper` which is extended to use a reentrant lock to ensure only one thread accesses the database at any one time. So the start of the code is like:

```
  MyDatabaseHelper dbConn = MyDatabaseHelper.getDatabaseAccess(c);//await availability/lock the database here
  SQLiteDatabase writer = dbConn.getWritableDatabase();     
    try
    {       
        writer.beginTransaction();

        //do inserts

        writer.setTransactionSuccessful();
```

Get database access as follows:

```
  public static MyDatabaseHelper getDatabaseAccess(Context c)
  {      
    l.lock();       
    return new MyDatabaseHelper(c);
  }
```

As a further test I have further added a `Thread.sleep()` call to the finally code (in my case of 12 seconds), before the `close()` but after the `endTransaction()`, that seems to have stopped the error and confirm it is not a case of an open cursor, but I would rather not rely on a timer. If there is a better way, perhaps to pre-check whether the database is busy, please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQLiteStatement or SQLiteQuery objects to work with your database you need to make sure they get closed out as well. If it's SQLiteClosable you need to close it.

Comment: I am ashamed to say, after all that, that once I went through and put the whole lot in try-finally blocks that the problem has been fixed. Whatever statement's close call was being missed is now calling.  I guess if it looks like a duck and quacks like a duck......

Comment: @user2145222 I've been there myself.

Answer (score 0):

This mainly happens when you haven't closed the cursor,  meant certain references to the database were invalid.

refer ths link  [Android SQLite Exception: unable to close due to unfinalised statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348603/android-sqlite-exception-unable-to-close-due-to-unfinalised-statements)

Comment: As I said, I have checked that.  And if it was that, wouldn't it happen every time the code ran? And wouldn't the loop above never exit?

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is incorrect. `close()` decrements a reference counter and only when the counter hits exactly zero is the actual resource disposal i.e. `sqlite3_close()` attempted. On the second call the counter will be negative and the call will be a no-op.

You are correct that error code 5 is `SQLITE_BUSY`.

Now to address the actual problem, please provide some additional details, such as how you open and configure the database and how you begin your transactions.

Comment: I have added a little more detail but I don't think I'm doing anything that special.  Are you saying that the workaround is wrong because even though an exception is not thrown the second time it still isn't closed?

Comment: @user2145222 The `while` loop in the workaround is useless. The exception is not thrown because the reference count is not exactly zero and the code that would throw is not called at all. Nothing obviously wrong in the updated question code but you could show what's in `getDatabaseAccess()`.

Comment: Added but it is just the basic code with the lock being set (I have added the release lock call to the code above as well, similarly this just calls the unlock()).

Comment: As now noted above I have added a thread.sleep before the close() and the error has disappeared.  I'm guessing the number of inserts I am doing is meaning the endTransaction() hasn't finished by the time I call close().

Comment: I have been testing a bit more. I changed my bad while loop 'fix' to be while(writer.isOpen()). From what you said about the behind the scenes stuff in .close() I assumed this would either endlessly loop (because after close failed once, it would never truly run again meaning isOpen is always true) or that it would run once (because despite the failure, close being called would still set this flag to false/closed) but instead, as before, it exits on the second iteration where the 'busy' error occurs.  Does this mean that if close fails cos it's busy, that it closes asap on its own?